# Prolog , endless loop

Tags: loops, prolog

I did t he following code to go through all student Ids starting from 476 and ending at 520.

```
schedule_errors(A,B,C):-
    Errors is 0,
    check_Courses(476,A,B,C,Errors).

check_Courses(X,A,B,C,Errors):-
   . .
   . .
   . .
   Y is X+1,
   check_Courses(Y,A,B,C,Er).
```

The problem is the programm keeps running indefinetly ignoring my exit loop predicate

```
check_Courses(520,A,B,C,Er):-
    write('Check complete').
```

I can't understand what i am doing wrong. i Tried a similar easier version (just counting to 10) and it works fine

```
loop(10):-
    write('cd finished').

loop(X):-
    write(X), nl,
    Y is X+1,
    loop(Y).
```

What am i missing?

Comment: i also used trace and it seems that when it reaches 520 it gets into the check_Courses(X,A,B,C,Errors):- and not the check_Courses(520,A,B,C,Er):- and keeps on looping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important observation is that `loop/1` **does not** terminate either. You can see this for example as follows:

```
?- loop(1), false.
1
2
3
...
8
9
cd finished10
11
12
13
14
...
49
50
51
...
32394
32395
...
```

Note that the *textual order* in which you state your clauses in Prolog matters.

If you exchange the two clauses of `loop/1`, then you do not get a single solution, only an endless stream of output:

```
?- loop(1).
...
42642
42643
...
```

So, in `check_courses/5`, if you put a more specific case after a case that subsumes it, then the textually first clause will always be tried first.

Put simple cases before more complex cases!